# Egit bare repository - Fetching

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

Hello I have a bare repository which acts as broker between a locally shared repository and a remote one(bitbucket).

It works quite good, I'm able to push changes without problems. Every change is automatically deployed first on the local repo then on the remote one.

The bare repo contains 2 branches: A remote and a local one.
In the "Configure Branch" tab, the remote branch is linked to the local.

The only problem occurs if I commit a change on the remote repo directly (e.g using the web interface), since while fetching, the change is not deployed to the local branch.

When I click on "Fetch from Upstream" the remote branch is updated but the local one isn't. It's like they're not bound altogether for fetching.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Pull option in order update your local copy with the remote.